# Reliable references for known user interface practices

Tags: website-design, gui-design

I have this problem, that I cannot find the studies, where there are said the facts that we all know, for example: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GUI_Design_Principles information in this page - are we supposed to take this as a lemma or as a definition without proof or has there been case studies for it - for example 9.1 (Minimize eye and hand movements, and other control actions.).

Basically the question is: If i wanted to find out the best user interface practices - I can google it and there will be millions of results like "7 best web interface practices".

I am looking for research papers where this has been proved or shown. Currently I am trying to prove that constant logging in is an annoying problem and I want reliable sources that prove something like this. (Something similar to point 9 from wikibooks article)

Another problem I am looking a solution for is: preferences should be saved. (Something similar to point 11 from wikibooks article).

Comment: This question may be too broad to be answerable in its current format.  You appear to be looking for a monolithic repository of UX design knowledge supported by research.  Is that correct?  I don't think any such unified repository of research exists, although [pattern libraries](http://uxmovement.com/resources/4-best-design-pattern-libraries/) may be a reasonable place to start.

Comment: Also, that "all functionality must be a few clicks away" is not a "fact that we all know".  Check out [uxmyths.com](http://uxmyths.com) where it is documented as [myth #2](http://uxmyths.com/post/654026581/myth-all-pages-should-be-accessible-in-3-clicks).  What matters is the scent of information, not the number of clicks.

Comment: This question is very unclear, and a bit all over the place really. You're asking several things all at once, and it's not really clear what your actual problem is. Can you refocus the question around the core issue (which appears to be about the impact on the user of constantly re-logging in) and *explain* that situation (is it an app / website?  What type of site it is etc) and what it is you're having issues with, and we'll try to answer it (citing sources and material evidence where found). But currently your question is too confusing to give a solid answer to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned in the questions, there is no such thing as a monlithic repository of UX design.
But, regarding your two questions at the end, I'd say you should be able to use Nielsens 10 Usability Heuristics for User Interface Design to sort it out.
http://www.nngroup.com/articles/ten-usability-heuristics/

> Recognition rather than recall Minimize the user's memory load by making objects, actions, and options visible. The user should not have to remember information from one part of the dialogue to another. Instructions for use of the system should be visible or easily retrievable whenever appropriate.

Nielsen even wrote about your login problem in this article: http://www.nngroup.com/articles/recognition-and-recall/

> The classic example of recall in an interface is login. When you log in to a site, you have to remember both a username (or email) and a password. You receive very few cues to help you with that memory retrieval: usually, just the site itself[...]

Nielsen heuristics (and a lot of his other work) is highly recommended for UX Design and has been proven right over time.

I hope this information helps you with your project.